# A simple homotopy lemma

Tags: algebraic-topology, general-topology

I'm trying to prove a lemma, suppose that $F:[0,1]×[0,1]→\bar{\mathbb{D}}$, a continuous function from the square to the closed disc, such that $F(t,0)=e^{2iπt}$, and in the other three borders, F is the constant map, i.e. $F(0,s)=F(1,s)=F(t,1)=\mathbf1$. Next, let U be the connected component of $(0,1)×{0}$ in $F^{−1}(\bar{\mathbb{D}}−{\mathbf1})$. How can I prove that ${\mathbf0∈F(U)}$?

Comment: This problem feels as an awkward (obscure) exercise (not research). On the top of it, you cannot proof the claim, there are counter-examples (I think).

Comment: @WlodAA The claim is true, F is a continuous map from a contractible set, so its image is contractible as well.

Comment: @user43326 a continuous image of contractible space does not have to be contractible, e.g. $S^1$ is an image of $[0,1]$, even quotient.

Comment: -- OP, try again.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I've got the answer.
We can construct a function as following:

$F'(x)=F(x)$, if $x$ is $\bar{U}$, and $F'(x)=1$, if not.

We can easily prove that $F'$ is continue, if $0\notin F(U)$, then $0\notin Im(F')$, this is impossible because $F'$ gives a homotopic equivalence between a degree 1 curve and a degree 0 curve. Therefore $0\in F(U)$.

Comment: Could you start your answer with a THEOREM?